# spinner clicking on EditText

Tags: android

When I click EditText, I want spinner to open the menu. When I click on textviewplaces, I want the spinner menu to be opened. How can I do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

private Spinner spinnerDevice;

     private static final String[] paths = {"......"};
    TextView textviewPlaces;

spinnerDevice = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerDevice);
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapterSpinnerDevice = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);
        textviewPlaces = findViewById(R.id.places_textView);

        adapterSpinnerDevice.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerDevice.setAdapter(adapterSpinnerLocation);
        spinnerDevice.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

XML File:

```
   <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/places_textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/location"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: For this you need to use AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: @berkoobek  did you check answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AutoCompleteTextView instead of it

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_line,
        paths);
//ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, paths); 

final AutoCompleteTextView textView;
textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

/*  textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(final View arg0) {
          textView.showDropDown();
      }
    });  */
```

Define UI element in your layout file

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
   android:id="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_width="match_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:ems="10" />
```

Comment: I did, but I'm getting a mistake. "void android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter) on a Null Object reference"

Comment: You have to put UI elemet of AutoTextView in your layout file whose id should be 'textView' ... Have you put it?

Comment: I added the XML file code on the subject, but I still get the same problem. "places_textView .setAdapter(arrayAdapter);" this line gives error

Comment: sorry, remove v from line ->   textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);  Edited answer plase check it

Comment: try using this line   ->  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
      (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, paths);

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this image
[AutoCompeleteTextView Exmaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxpq3.gif)

Arwy Shelke answer can help you, but if you want to open a real spinner you can use this code:

```
spinner.performClick();
```